# How to create and submit a form using Java Script

Tags: javascript, web-services, firefox, multipartform-data

I'm writing a Firefox extension that's to be used in house. Basically, I need to submit a pdf file and some text values to a web service. Right now I have a html page that does this. I need the extension to automate the gathering and submission of the data to the web service.

Here's the html that works.

```
<body>
<form name="frm_upload_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="my web service address">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>ClientID</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="client_id" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>HTML</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="html" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="right" class="inputtxt"> File: </td>
   <td class="inputtxt">

       <input name="pdf" type="file" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="left" colspan="2" class="inputtxt">
       <p><br /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's the javascript that doesn't

```
postToURL: function(html, file) {
var form = content.document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "address to my web service");

var clientIDField = document.createElement("input");
clientIDField.setAttribute("type", "text");
clientIDField.setAttribute("name", "client_id");
clientIDField.setAttribute("value", "123456");
form.appendChild(clientIDField);

var htmlField = document.createElement("input");
htmlField.setAttribute("type", "text");
htmlField.setAttribute("name", "html");
htmlField.setAttribute("value", html);
form.appendChild(htmlField);    

var fileField = document.createElement("input");
fileField.setAttribute("type", "file");
fileField.setAttribute("name", "pdf");
fileField.setAttribute("value", file);
form.appendChild(fileField);

content.document.body.appendChild(form);    
form.submit();
```

When submitting the data with the js, I get the following exception from the server.
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Missing start boundary

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can create and populate a filefield like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the value  of a file input - otherwise you could steal files from people's machines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify the value of a `<input type="file">` field for security reasons. You'll likely need to find another way of automating this.